# Upload file to server and delete original using NET::SCP gem in Ruby

Tags: ruby, scp

I'm using the `net/scp` gem to upload a file from my machine to a remote Linux server.

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/scp'

Net::SCP.upload!(10.125.0.0,
                user,
                local_path,
                remote_dir,
                :ssh => { :password => psw,
                          :key_data => keys})
```

This works perfectly, however I'd like to be able to 'move' the file instead of effectively copying it across.

Is there some `scp`parameter that will delete the original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Net::SCP doesn't have any such parameter:

https://github.com/net-ssh/net-scp/blob/master/lib/net/scp.rb#L259-L267

Since the only difference between a copy and a move is just a final deletion of the source, you should do this manually after `upload!`.

```
File.delete(local_path)
```

You most likely will want to make sure that Net::SCP has finished before doing so:

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/scp'

channel = Net::SCP.upload!(10.125.0.0,
                user,
                local_path,
                remote_dir,
                :ssh => { :password => psw,
                          :key_data => keys})
channel.wait
File.delete(local_path)
```

Comment: Ok thanks. According to your link, using `upload!` is "_identical to calling upload and then calling the wait method on the channel object_" so adding `wait` is superfluous in this instance.